# How to send request to Business Profile Performance API in java for getting search keywords?

Tags: java, google-my-business-api, google-business-profile-api

I am using  [Business Profile Performance API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest/v1/locations.searchkeywords.impressions.monthly/list) to get the search keywords used to find a business in search or maps. Supposing business_profile_performance is the initializer variable of type `BusinessProfilePerformance` API which also takes care of credentials:

```
                try{ 
                   BusinessProfilePerformance.Locations.Searchkeywords.Impressions.Monthly.List impressionsList= business_profile_performance.
locations().searchkeywords().impressions().monthly().list("locations/"+locationName);               
                ListSearchKeywordImpressionsMonthlyResponse response = impressionsList.execute();
                                        List<SearchKeywordCount>  impressions = response.getSearchKeywordsCounts();
                                         System.out.println("Size is "+ impressions.size());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

It gives me error :

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "details" : [ {
    "@type" : "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest"
  } ],
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer, I was not sending months range:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        
        localDate= localDate.minusMonths(1);
        int endYear= localDate.getYear() ;
        int endMonth= localDate.getMonthValue() ;
        
        localDate= localDate.minusMonths(1);
        int startYear= localDate.getYear() ;
        int startMonth= localDate.getMonthValue() ;
     
        try {

            BusinessProfilePerformance.Locations.Searchkeywords.Impressions.Monthly.List impressions
            = business_profile_performance.locations().searchkeywords().impressions().monthly().list("locations/"+locationName)
            
            .setMonthlyRangeEndMonthYear(endYear)
            .setMonthlyRangeEndMonthMonth(endMonth)
             
            .setMonthlyRangeStartMonthYear(startYear)
            .setMonthlyRangeStartMonthMonth(startMonth);

            ListSearchKeywordImpressionsMonthlyResponse response = impressions.execute();    
            System.out.println(response.toString());


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```